# How to Find the Highest Ranked ANSWER(S) on the site?

Tags: support

How can I find the highest ranked ANSWERS on the site?

Context:

I recently was a part of [Which word begins with "y" and looks like an axe in this picture?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395382/which-word-begins-with-y-and-looks-like-an-axe-in-this-picture/395385#395385) and have tried to see other high voted answers (trying to see if this is the All-Time record holder - currently at 753)

Was able to sort by highest ranked person etc but not this that I can find...

*the answer was provided by https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/55623/dan-bron

ps
Does anyone else feel like this is the place where everything u type is going to be seen by the best in the grammar world?

Comment: Go to the search box. Type `is:a`, it will list all answers and only answers. Change sort to *by votes*. Voila. And I find most people on this site find novel grammar *interesting*, rather than judging it. Like a lepidopterologist capturing a a new specimen. Well, mostly ;)

Comment: everything u type is going to be seen by the best in the grammar world? -- literally true! So I always try to aspire to linguistic perfection when posting *anything* here -- I was thinking what search might help you... Then Dan Bron posted an 'inside search' method and it *works like a charm!* The Swedish axe is indeed the new record for most upvoted answer, surpassing the previous record, set 6 years back, by another 50% (*half as much again* in plain English) and counting...

Comment: Did that graphic designer ever get back to you, BTW? Inquiring minds want to know!

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A400

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can restrict your search to answers only with `is:a` ([help](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/searching) lists this and other advanced search tips) and then click the "votes" tab. You should end up [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa%20). As you can see, as of now, it's the highest scoring answer... on ELU.

But what about the whole SE network?

I made [a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/692865/all-sites-top-10-answers) that selects the `top 10` answers from each site (including metas). [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa) easily outscores every other site, with the [highest-scoring answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/6083675) having a net score of **24791**.

Comment: I ask a question. |
Several helpful replies  |
I feel at home here  |

haiku = thanks (not able to format)

Comment: Great answer, @Laurel, yours! I upvote. You have also linked to the most upvoted answer ever on SE, which seems excellent indeed, except that computer code is all Greek to me.